# Why can I tell when to stop filling a glass based on the pitch of the water?

Tags: acoustics

If you fill a glass of water, the sound pitch of the water increases as the glass gets more and more full.

The other night I was filling a glass in the dark and I noticed something - I could intuitively tell when the glass was nearly full purely based on the sound. And then I tested a few other containers and it seemed like I could hear the same “just about full” sound in tall water bottles, tea mugs, small cups, etc. This struck me as odd because these containers all have different shapes and volumes.

Now, it’s entirely possible that the sounds are actually different and that I’m subconsciously using a combination of Lived Experience and the fact that the containers get heavier as they become more full to gauge when to stop filling. But I was wondering if there was a possibility that the sound a nearly-full water container makes really is the same across the range of containers I tried. Is that the case? If so, why is that, given that they’re made of different materials, have different heights, and have different volumes?

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is the sound of filling a container with liquid always the same regardless of container?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/300155/)

Comment: Re, "sound pitch of the water..." I disagree with the "duplicate" answer. IMO, the "pitch" that you hear is because the air in the space _above_ the water resonates like in an [open-ended organ pipe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acoustic_resonance#Closed_at_one_end). The pitch rises as the rising water level shortens the length of the "pipe." The effect is (again, IMO) more pronounced when you're filling a tall cylindrical vessel.

Comment: @SolomonSlow Care to expand that into an answer? :-)