# Frequency of water bottle as it is being filled

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, fluid-dynamics, acoustics

Suppose you open the knob of a filter and water drops from it at a rate of 'n' (volume/sec). You place down a cup, whose bottom is at a height 'h' below the knob. Suppose water comes to rest just after collision with cup (and whatever water is inside it at that moment). Neglect any other losses. Can you calculate the frequency of the sound heard as a function of time? You can assume anything else needed but please mention it in the answer. Is this problem do-able for a 12th grade student?

Comment: It would depend on the material of the cup, shape of the cup, size of the cup's face, what the cup is kept on, what medium we are in etc etc.

Comment: Without the shape of the cup I can't see how you would even approximately answer this; unless it's something trivial like $f(t) = 0$.

Comment: I wrote in my question that you could assume anything you want, for e.g. cup to be cylindrical, medium to be air, area to be 'A', etc.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Frequency of the sound when blowing in a bottle](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/44601)

Comment: @ParthBahuguna Allowing us to assume anything we want isn't a good question format IMO.  It's far too broad.  I could just say "There's obviously no frequency; because I'm assuming this is in a vacuum".

Comment: I'm sorry if I wasn't specific. I meant just normal things Like you do in everyday life.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. model the cup as an organ pipe with a random noise source at its closed end and the distant end open. it will exhibit a resonance which produces the pitch of the noise you hear coming out of the cup as it fills; the formula for the pitch of an organ pipe open at the far end of the noise source can be found here or elsewhere on the web (your homework! ;-) . During the time it is filling, the length of this organ pipe is steadily decreasing as the cup fills to the brim and the pitch it produces will steadily rise in frequency. Knowing the dimensions of the cup and the flow rate of water into it, you can solve for the organ pipe length versus time and from that get the pitch versus time relationship. Be sure to have as much fun as possible while you do this!

Comment: Thanks man, yes I would have fun :D but should the frequency be the first harmonic?

Comment: the organ pipe formula will tell you what the fundmental will be- and a quick experiment will tell you if the system is resonating at the fundamental or a higher harmonic. Most systems like this resonate at the fundamental unless the resonating tube has been designed to suppress the fundamental and accentuate the harmonics.

Answer (score 1):

What is it, a bottle or a cup?

A cup would act as a very short organ pipe, but a bottle would have the much lower resonances of a Helmholtz oscillator. Rod Nave's site has data about the cavity resonance of a Coke bottle as a function of volume: http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Waves/coke.html

They also did different sized sizes, and a plastic Coke bottle.