# Measured frequency of the sound produced when blowing in a bottle is half of calculated

Tags: acoustics, frequency, resonance

Preparing one lecture about resonance in cylindrical tubes with one closed end, I decided to make some experiments to compare calculated frequencies and measured ones.

We can find anwhere ([click here](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Waves/clocol.html), for example) that the frequencies in such cylindrical tubes match the following formula:
$$ f_n = n \cdot \frac{c}{4L}, $$
where $n = 1, 3, 5, 7, ...$, $c \approx 330~\mathrm{m/s}$ is the speed of sound in air, and $L$ is the length of the tube. For one experiment, I used a bottle with $L = 22.5~\mathrm{cm}$ (see the figure below), so that the first resonant frequency is expected to be $f_1 = 367~\mathrm{Hz}$. However, I used a mobile app called **Sound Analyzer** ([click here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=processing.test.soundanalyzer&hl=pt) to install) and measured half of that value. I repeated this test for different bottles, always finding the same discrepancy of a factor of half.

Searching in the internet, I found some pages and articles about Helmholtz resonance, as can be found here: [Frequency of the sound when blowing in a bottle](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/44601/frequency-of-the-sound-when-blowing-in-a-bottle).

Every page or paper about Helmholtz resonance present the formula for the frequency:
$$ f = \frac{c}{2\pi} \sqrt{\frac{A}{LV}}, $$
where $L$ is the length of the neck of the tube, $A$ is the area of the aperture, and $V$ is the volume of the resonant cavity.

Using Helmholtz formula, therefore, I measured the neck to be $L = 9~\mathrm{cm}$, $A = 3,80~\mathrm{cm^2}$, and $V = 450~\mathrm{mL}$, so that $f \approx 161~\mathrm{Hz}$, much closer than the first calculation.

But I belive that the bottle is quite close to a cylinder, so that manipulating the Helmholtz formula, approaching the generalized, I made $V = AL$, so that the final formula turns to
$$ f = \frac{c}{2\pi L}, $$
which is somwhat different from the first equation at the beginning of this question.

My question is, why I always measure half of the calculated frequency for the first resonance mode of one closed end cylinder, no matter the bottle I try (as long as it is a bottle with behaved shape similar to the one in the picture)?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

*I measured the neck to be L= 9 cm* The value of $L$ (the **effective** length) which you have entered into the Helmholtz resonance formula is probably the source of your discrepancy as it is not well defined with your bottle with a tapered neck and there is also an extra length correction to be made as one would do with the end correction for a cylindrical tube.

UNSW (University of New South Wales) has an excellent acoustics section on the [Helmholtz resonator](https://newt.phys.unsw.edu.au/jw/Helmholtz.html) which explains what correction you might make.

At the end of the page there is a [.wav file of frequency 90 Hz](https://newt.phys.unsw.edu.au/jw/sounds/Helmholtz1.mp3) which you could use to check the calibration of your spectrum analyser.

See also the answers to the post [Frequency of the sound when blowing in a bottle](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/44601/frequency-of-the-sound-when-blowing-in-a-bottle) and by taking a set of frequency readings for different volumes you can estimate the effective length of your resonator.